# Restart tor service using php script

Tags: php, linux, command-line

I know there's a other questions is similar to my question but in need a different way

i need to restart tor service using `exec`

and it's works if i used `exec('sudo service tor restart');` in my php script

after add this line `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` to `sudoers` file

but i think this is too risky to do  i tried to do that using .sh file like

`exec("sh /file/tor.sh");` but did not work either

Is there a safe and simple way to do that?

Comment: You shoud create a .sh file for restart Tor service that doesn't require any password (maybe you can create a new user for this purpose? Idk, this si related to the system administration copy). If the .sh will work for the shell, it will work in your php

Comment: @lorenzo_campanile Will it be safer to use `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/killall` ?